# Creating a dataframe column resulting from Groupby and transform

Tags: pandas, group-by, transform

I have a dataframe of 4 columns textID, A, B,C

I would like create a groupby object and then calculate the 5th percentile on column C and then add this column (calling it 'quantile') back to the original dataframe.

I have this following code that works when groupby is on one column

```
df2['quantile']=df2.C.groupby(df2.itextID).transform(lambda x: 
x.quantile(q=0.5))
```

Question 1:
How can this be extended so the groupby object is now using two columns i.e. textID & A?

Question 2:
Can the groupby object be created first and then the transform applied?
i.e.

```
### Create groupby object Extract top 4 rows in each group
grp = df2.groupby('textID').head(4)
??? how to apply the transform to column C?
```

Thanks

(Can square brackets notation be used rather than dot?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use alternative with columns names in list inside `groupby` and specify columns after `groupby` for processing `transform` or another function:

```
df2['quantile']= (df2.groupby(['itextID', 'A'])['C']
                     .transform(lambda x: x.quantile(q=0.5)))
```

Here `grp` is DataFrame, not `groupby` object, because [`GroupBy.head`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.head.html) return `DataFrame`:

```
grp = df2.groupby('textID').head(4)
```

---

But is possible create `groupby` object by removing `.head(4)`:

```
grp = df2.groupby('textID')
```

And then use `head`:

```
df = grp.head(4)
```

Or `transform`:

```
df2['new'] = grp['C'].transform(lambda x: x.quantile(q=0.5))
```

Comment: Thanks, how would you combine head and transform, just chain them?

Comment: @user11305439 It is a bit problem, because `head`  filtering, it means there is less rows after apply it. Function `transform` working differently, thwre is no filtering. So chain together is problem like `df1 = df2.groupby('textID').head(4). transform(function)`.  So need filtering first `df3 = df2.groupby('textID').head(4)` and then create new column by `df3['new'] =  df3.groupby('textID')['C'].transform(lambda x: x.quantile(q=0.5))`